# ¿Es posible crear una cuenta de GMAIL con php?

Tags: php, email

Tengo que crear cuentas de **GMAIL** con php, pero por ahora no encuentro información acerca del tema, Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Hola, revisa los links de este enlace de SO[EN] quizá pueda serte de ayuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527171/programmatically-create-gmail-accounts-using-php

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. ¿Te refieres a crear cuentas dentro de un entorno de GSuite o algo así?  Además, debes decir lo que has investigado/intentado al respecto. ¿Por qué tiene que ser en PHP?  [Mira  un ejemplo para embeber el formulario de creación de cuentas de Google en cualquier sitio web](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/), es en Javascript, del lado del cliente. Solamente necesitarás un ID DE CLIENTE para ponerlo en lugar de `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` donde dice `content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps ....`

Comment: Si de todos modos quieres hacerlo del lado del servidor (o sea, en PHP),  entonces puedes revisar el artículo titulado *[Google Sign-In for server-side apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow)*, donde se explica cómo gestionar la creación de cuentas del lado del servidor. Ahora bien, dan ejemplos de código usando solamente `Java`  o `Phyton`. Te toca investigar si se puede mediante PHP. Dependiendo de lo que quieras, es algo que se puede hacer mediante Javascript, sin complicarse con código de servidor.